# Parse.com android cannot receive JSON push notification

Tags: android, json, parsing, push-notification, parse-platform

I have been eating my brains for hours and cannot find an answer.
My problem is that I am trying to send push notifications to my android device from the Parse.com console on the web and when I send a message there is no problem but if I try to send JSON then I will never see the notification on my device.

I am trying to send a JSON message as simple as this-> {"x":"1"}

my relevant manifest code

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="my.app.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.app.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


       <!-- Parse push notification receiver -->
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="my.app.package" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="my.app.package.parse.NotificationReceiver" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

my.app.package.parse.NotificationReceiver exists normally and handles the application opening successfully for the message notifications

and my Application's onCreate() runs the following

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "..........", ".............");

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("everything", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```

I have run out of ideas so Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My next idea solved my problem.
It seems that a JSON message should include a tag "alert" with the value of the text that is needed to be shown as a notification.

If "alert" tag is not specified then the notification is not shown. So my `{"x":"1"}` would not show up but

```
{ "x": "1", "alert": "show me to the user" }
```

is showing up normally.
Unfortunately I did not find this anywhere in parse user guide, so PLEASE Parsers add this to the guides to let other developers not waste time.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, parse documentation really miss important stuffs, Do you have an idea where they explain how to receive and process JSON push notification ?

Comment: You can start here https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android but the real guide to receiving is here https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications.

I subclassed ParsePushBroadcastReceiver to read the JSON payload of the push notification my own way and act accordingly

Comment: @KlitosG.  i m failed to recieve parse push notification as i m sending json with alert as well

Comment: @Erum I do not know if you have already solved your problem, but are you sure the notification is reaching your phone? In my case the alert did the trick, but this was a couple of parse versions lower than today. Please check that this has not changed

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify that the POST you are sending is of type `application/json`

By default, the POST has a media type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This will obviously not be recognized as JSON by the machine.